# Control border height with JS

Tags: javascript, php, css, drupal-7

I have two Divs on top of each other: `#header-menu` and below is `#banner`. Both are spanning the full width of `#body`.

Both of them have `a {border-bottom:5px}`. But when `#banner` is empty (I only puth things in it on certain pages) then the `border-bottom` on `#header-menu` will be 5px + the 5px from the border of `#banner` and that kills the design.

My question is if I by using JS and CSS can take away the border of `#banner` if `#banner` is less than 5px heigh? If so, how to do it then?

I'm on Drupal 7, can I do it in php so when `#banner` is empty then there will be borders?

Comment: post the relevant code (html & js)

Comment: What have you tried using? You can detect and manipulate the style properties of the elements using JS.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are asking to do

```
$(".banner").each(function(){
  if( $(this).height() < 5){
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Or:

```
$(".banner").each(function(){
  if( $(this).html() == ''){
    $(this).css('border-bottom', 'none');
  }
});
```

For every banner on the page, read it's html. if the html is empty, then set the banner's css border-bottom property to none. However, I'd suggest that if its empty, its a pointless html element, so better would be to remove it like this:

```
$(".banner").each(function(){
  if( $(this).html() == ''){
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

(here I've used `.banner` rather than `#banner`)

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/qNQwOQ

However I'd urge you to use some kind of server side code to just not output the html if the div is going to be empty.

Comment: I changed from .banner to #banner and have tried with both versions as preprocessed, in node.tpl, page.tpl html.tpl and in the Drupal Code per node-module and nothing happends. What can be wrong?